# xml attribute parsing in scala

Tags: xml, scala

I am trying to validate stuff against an xml schema. I am getting an input from user and checking to see if that value exist as a value for the name attribute. If it does i am returning true or if not false. Ive loaded the schema into a val and selected the nodes that i want like

```
val a = XML.load("schema.xml")
val nodes = (a \\ "Items")
```

Now a has the following

```
<Items name="name1" type="type1" />
<Items name="name2" type="type2" />
<Items name="name3" type="type3" />
<Items name="name4" type="type4" />
```

The user inputs the value *name1*

I tried doing

```
nodes.foreach(checkattr(_))

checkattr(val : elem)
{
  if(elem@name == userinput) { true } else { false }
}
```

But this is nt working and even if it does it seems the wrong way to do it as i want to return true or false only once for the entire traversal instead of the likes of waht  i have specified above.

Any pointers would be useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was searching for:

```
val isThere = dataItems \\ "@name" find { _.text == name }
if (isThere != None)
  return true
else
  false
```

Posted it as it might be useful for some one else too

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you want is something like:

```
scala> <foo baz="quux"/> \ "@baz"
res0: scala.xml.NodeSeq = quux

scala>
```

Comment: what happens if there are multiple baz attributes, i tried it and it only returns a null array

Comment: @swordfish - Valid XML allows only a single attribute by a given name, doesn't it?